# Angular Material Theme Is Not Getting Applied with Angular version 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have an angular application with version 11 and I am using angular material with version 11 as well

**Issue :**

The angular material theme is not getting applied even after doing below things :

1. Added below theme in src/style.scss

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

2. Added imports for different components in `app.module.ts` for angular material

3)Please note that I am using style.scss

### **Code :**
**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### **package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

Is there anything I am missing here ?
All the posts I have reseacrhed on internet talk about adding above things which I have already done
Can you please help ?

Comment: Sometimes, for reasons beyond my knowledge, Angular won't refresh even if you have implemented a correct behavior. As stupid as it may be, have you first tried to Reload your IDE?

Comment: @Atul Can you share your complete code?